# Image Hosting CDN with Custom Domain and Unlimited Traffic

Tags: image, networking, hosting, cdn, vps

HI I am looking for an image hosting cdn with custom domain (http://images.example.com/demoimages1.jpg) and unlimited traffic.

The problem with Amazon S3, Rackspace etc is that: they are pay as you go and thats quite expensive when your site grows bigger.

Does anyone know such image hosting cdn?

If there is none, I am considering using a VPS. Who can recommend a VPS with small storage space but large traffic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the CDN hosting providers will charge you "Pay-AS-You-Go" model. CDN is a business purely based on traffic (bandwidth). So, most of the hosting providers are offering "Pay-AS-You-Go" model. You can try out dediserve.com - I am using them for one of my website and they are charging you a fix amount per Edge location per month.

Regarding VPS recommendations, what is your traffic requirement. You can easily find a [decent VPS provider](http://www.accuwebhosting.com/) offering 100 to 200 GIG of Bandwidth for $15 to $20 per Month.